# Monitoring Azure via Jenkins

Tags: azure, jenkins

We currently have our source-code in Bitbucket. Which in his turn, deploys the development code to Azure.
We have a local Jenkins instance that we want to use to perform some tests against the Azure instance.

Is there a possibility to monitor Azure and start running tests when the deploy has finished?
If I just poll the SCM I have no guarantee that the app is deployed, I will only know that someone checked in some code.

Thanks in advance.
Regards

Comment: Bitbucket is just an SCM and can't deploy code. Bamboo is the Atlassian tool deploys code. Is this that what you use to deploy code or do you use Jenkins for everything?

Comment: Can you define "monitor azure"? If you're using Kudu to deploy then you can find the commit id in /api/settings. Not completely sure about the URL, just check the landing page when you login to Kudu, it's in the bullet list.

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have explained it better. Azure monitors Bitbucket and deploys a new version when an SCM change is detected. We have tests that are in another codebase than the codebase that is monitored by Azure. So if we just put the test codebase in Jenkins and monitor for SCM changes, this will not take into account deployment of the other codebase on Azure. This is why we need something to 'monitor' Azure and tell Jenkins when a new version is deployed on Azure. Then the tests on Jenkins should start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article helped me fix the problem: https://microsoft.github.io/techcasestudies/azure%20app%20service/devops/2016/12/20/Arena.html

The key is to use their code example to create the PostDeploymentActions folder and copy any scripts to that folder after the deployment. They will get executed autonatically if you are using Kudu.